# Handling Unhandled promise rejection in express application

Tags: node.js, express, exception, unhandled-exception, unhandled-promise-rejection

I have an existing Node Express Application and want to improve the error handling better. My current route endpoint definition is like below,

```
app.get('/example/getActiveId', async (req, res, next) => {
  // Some code to fetch some details from request and do some validations

  try {
    const result = await api.getActiveId(id); 
    res.json({ success: true, result });       // I am getting this response in all the time.
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('getActiveId', err)
    console.error(err);
    res.json({ success: false });
  }
});
```

Also, I defined error middleware at the last of all the route paths.

```
// error handler middleware
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  console.log('in Error middleware')
  console.error(error.stack);
  res.status(500).send(error.message || 'Something Broke!');
 })
```

My definition of `getActiveId` is as below.

```
 exports.getActiveId = id => axiosInstance
  .get('/example')
  .then(({ data }) => data)
  .catch(er => er);
```

The problem in the above `getActiveId` definition is every time the catch of the `getActiveId`, the execution falls into the try block of the above endpoint definition. I wanted the execution should go into the catch block endpoint definition function. So that I could call `next(err)` to call the default express error handling middleware.

So I tried the following mockup code to mimic the same with promise reject.

```
exports.getActiveId = id => {
    const __mockPromise = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            reject('Problem in getActiveId')
        })
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        __mockPromise().then(({ data }) => resolve(data)).catch(er => { console.log('in catch....'); reject(er) })
    });
}
```

I expected the above function will go into the catch block of the end point function definition.

But this time I am getting the following error,

```
in catch....
(node:32897) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Problem in getActiveId
(node:32897) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
```

How can I fix this error and bypass the execution to error middleware?

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, `api.getActiveId` always returns a *resolved* promise

- if the `axiosInstance.get` succeeds, it resolves to the `data`
- if the `axiosInstance.get` fails, the `.catch(er => er)` makes it resolve to the `er`.

If you want `api.getActiveId` to return a promise that is *rejected* with `er`, omit the `.catch(er => er)`.

For example, if you run Node.js with the following input

```js
const getActiveId = () => Promise.reject("error")
  .then(({ data }) => data);
async function test() {
  try {
    const result = await getActiveId();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
test();
```

the `console.error` statement will be reached and no unhandled promise rejection will be reported.

Comment: Can we do the same with the Mock function? If I do your steps above, I am getting,
```Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your mock function. If `api.getActiveId` returns a rejected promise, the `catch` in your async middleware will handle that.

Comment: I couldn't send make the error case of axis instance. So I made a mockup function which able to post a reject call and test my code. But its not working as the way it should.

Comment: Indeed, when I try the same, the rejection is handled by my `catch` block.

Comment: But I am getting all the responses to try block of API endpoint definition. means, I am getting {success: true}. But for failure response of Axios call (or) mockup call, I need to get {success: false}

Comment: When I run this: `const getActiveId = () => Promise.reject("error")
 .then(({ data }) => data);

async function test() {
 try {
  const result = await getActiveId(); 
  console.log(result);
 } catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
 }
}

test();`, I get to the `console.error`, no unhandled promise. Same for you?

Comment: ```Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
```
getting this